# get movement of user in action down in android activity

Tags: android

i am working on a app where i need to get . the direction of the user drag his finger  on the screen in Action.Down (before he lift his finger)
if i coded some code but it tell the values only after user lift his finger from the mobile activity .  but i want the direction of user movement while his finger is placed on the screen

```
layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    // store the X value when the user's finger was pressed down
                    downXValue = event.getX();
                    downYValue = event.getY();
                    Log.d("recording", "= " + downYValue);
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    // Get the X value when the user released his/her finger
                    float currentX = event.getX();
                    float currentY = event.getY();
                    // check if horizontal or vertical movement was bigger

                    if (Math.abs(downXValue - currentX) > Math.abs(downYValue
                            - currentY)) {
                        Log.d("recording", "x");
                        // going backwards: pushing stuff to the right
                        if (downXValue < currentX) {
                            Log.d("recording", "right");

                        }

                        // going forwards: pushing stuff to the left
                        if (downXValue > currentX) {
                            Log.d("recording", "left");

                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.d("recording", "y ");

                        if (downYValue < currentY) {
                            Log.d("recording", "down");




                            }
                        }
                        if (downYValue > currentY) {
                            Log.d("recording", "up");




                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }

            }

            return true;

        }


    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` instead `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`

**ACTION_MOVE**

> Constant for getActionMasked(): A change has happened during a press
>   gesture (between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP). The motion contains the
>   most recent point, as well as any intermediate points since the last
>   down or move event.

**ACTION_UP**

> Constant for getActionMasked(): A pressed gesture has finished, the
>   motion contains the final release location as well as any intermediate
>   points since the last down or move event.

Try this:

```
layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    // store the X value when the user's finger was pressed down
                    downXValue = event.getX();
                    downYValue = event.getY();
                    Log.d("recording", "= " + downYValue);
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    // Get the X value when the user released his/her finger
                    float currentX = event.getX();
                    float currentY = event.getY();
                    // check if horizontal or vertical movement was bigger

                    if (Math.abs(downXValue - currentX) > Math.abs(downYValue
                            - currentY)) {
                        Log.d("recording", "x");
                        // going backwards: pushing stuff to the right
                        if (downXValue < currentX) {
                            Log.d("recording", "right");

                        }

                        // going forwards: pushing stuff to the left
                        if (downXValue > currentX) {
                            Log.d("recording", "left");

                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.d("recording", "y ");

                        if (downYValue < currentY) {
                            Log.d("recording", "down");




                            }
                        }
                        if (downYValue > currentY) {
                            Log.d("recording", "up");




                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }

            }

            return true;

        }


    });
```

Comment: can you please explain it with some source code i am newby in android

Comment: i was just thinking about these conditions

Comment: If it's worked for you can you please accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: i will i am testing it

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: can i ask one more thing

Comment: yeah sure go ahead?

Comment: one of my account is blocked few days i cant post question from that account

Comment: a message is there that we are no longer accepting questions from this account

Comment: can you tell me how to unlock that account

Comment: Check this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)